# mvc button does not do anything when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

So I fixed the issue from a previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758377/many-to-many-relationship-in-mvc-and-ef), now I am getting what I was looking for but when I hit save it does nothing? No error or postback and nothing saved to the database? The button doesn't do anything in my view?

I have a many to many relationship with Post and Tag in my EF Model. I am trying to assign a post to a tag. I was following this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702890/MVC-Entity-Framework-and-Many-to-Many-Relation). However the button does nothing when I click save.

**PostController:**

```
public ActionResult EditPostTag(int id = 12) // hardcoded the post for now
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var postsViewModel = new PostsViewModel
    {
        posts = db.Posts.Include(i => i.Tags).First(i => i.Id == id),
    };

    if (postsViewModel.posts == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    var tagsList = db.Tags.ToList();
    postsViewModel.Tags = tagsList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = o.Name,
        Value = o.Id.ToString()
    });

    ViewBag.UserID =
            new SelectList(db.BlogUsers, "UserID", "Email", postsViewModel.posts.Id);

    return View(postsViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Where is the <form tag? you missed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view does not have a `form` tag

```
@model MyBlogger.ViewModel.PostsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditPostTag";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>EditPostTag</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) // add this
{
    ....
}
```

**Edit** (further to comments and some misunderstanding by OP)

Using a view model as you have done is always good practice however you are not taking advantage of it by continuing to use `ViewBag` and using it to hold a data model instead of including just the properties you need to the view. I recommend it be

```
public class PostViewModel // its for a single post - not plural?
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a title")]
  public string Title { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Tags")] // plus [Required] is at least one tag must be selected
  public List<int> SelectedTags { get; set; }
  public SelectList TagsList { get; set; }
  // Its unclear if you really need the following 2 properties (see notes)
  [Display(Name = "User")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a user")]
  public int UserID { get; set; }
  public SelectList UserList { get; set; }
}
```

Side note: Its a bit unclear why you are allowing the user to select another user to be associated with the `Post` object. I suspect that when you save the `Post` you should be just assigning the current user in the controllers POST method

Your controller methods would then be (assume this is `PostController`)

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  Post post = db.Posts.Include(i => i.Tags).FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id); // First() will throw an exception is the item is not found
  if (post == null) { return HttpNotFound(); }
  PostViewModel model = new PostViewModel()
  {
    ID = post.ID,
    Title = post.Title,
    SelectedTags = post.Tags.Select(t => t.Id)
  }; // include UserId property?
  ConfigureEditModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(PostViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureEditModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  // map your view model to a data model, save it and redirect
}

private void ConfigureEditModel(PostViewModel model)
{
  model.TagsList = new SelectList(db.Tags, "Id", "Name");
  model.UserList = new BlogUsers(db.Tags, "UserID", "Email"); // ??
}
```

Side note: Either `SelectList` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is acceptable (I find `SelectList` easier to read but its a millisecond or two slower because it uses reflection to generate the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) but there is no point using the 4th parameter as you did with `new SelectList(db.BlogUsers, "UserID", "Email", postsViewModel.posts.Id);` - your binding to a property and the selected item will be the value of the property, so trying to set the `Selected` property is just ignored)

And finally the view (simplified to show only helpers without html attributes)

```
@model MyBlogger.ViewModel.PostViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  // @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.posts.Id) not required
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
  // Is the UserId property required?
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserID)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserID, Model.UserList, "Please select")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserID)
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedTags)
  @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags, Model.TagsList)
  // Add ValidationMessageFor() if at least one should be selected
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Side note: Since the parameter of your method is named `id`, the value of the `id` property will be added to the route parameters so it is not necessary to add a hidden input for the view models `ID` property (the `DefaultModelBinder` reads route values in addition to form values, so the view models `ID` property will be correctly bound (to `12` in you case)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, all that work and it still didnt work. Database isnt showing the id's in PostTagMap....

Comment: You need to include the `[HttpPost]` method in your question - all you have shown is GET method. It would need a signature like `[HttpPost] public ActionResult EditPostTag(PostsViewModel model)`

Comment: Your current signature `public ActionResult EditPostTag(int id = 12)` is not receiving the viewmodel with the values that the user inputs

Comment: IMHO that's not a good tutorial and has some practices, but its actually in the tutorial - at the bottom just before the "Conclusion" heading

Comment: I added in `[HttpPost] public ActionResult EditPostTag(PostsViewModel model){ return View(model) }` and I get   `The ViewData item that has the key 'posts.BlogUser.UserID' is of type 'System.Guid' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` when I click save....

Comment: I couldn't find many tutorials on working with many to many relationships in mvc and EF.

Comment: That's because you have not reassigned the values of the `SelectLists` and the `Tags` property (as you did in the GET method) before you return the view. Give me an hour or so and I will update my answer with the code I would recommend

Comment: Hey just to let you know @StephenMuecke I managed it. It was in the comments section for the httppost method, just had to change a few things but it works now!

Comment: @GarrithGraham, Have edited the answer with some suggestions and explanations that hopefully will help with your understanding.

Comment: Hi Stephen, yeah I was going to try fix the user being able to see other users. I also have an issue with the int id, if I set it to int? id = 0 it returns nothing. This wasn't suppose to be an "Edit" originally it was me trying to work out how I could add a tag to a post when a user first creates a post. However I have now went down a confusing path and cant work out how to achieve this. My Create Post View is bound to the Post Model so I cant add in tags...

Comment: Not sure I understand which bit your struggling with. The method for creating a new post would be `public ActionResult Create() { PostViewModel model = new PostViewModel(); ConfigureEditModel(model); return View(model); }` (no parameter), and then in the corresponding POST method you would map the properties to a new data model and insert it in the database